# aws jupyter-notebook don't show graph tab after changed gremlin settings

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I'm trying to make local gremlin server as similar as possible to aws neptune.

After edit the property file

> tinkergraph-custom.properties

with content:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=UUID
gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=UUID
```

Everything works well, except that [jupyter-notebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/graph-notebooks.html) that I'm using as client don't draw graph tab anymore
[image]

Comment: I need to check, but I suspect the underlying rendering code is not UUID aware enough to make sense of the result. If you use string or numeric IDs does it work OK? If other ID types work, would you be able to open an issue on the graph-notebook GIT repo?

Comment: I tried with *IdManager=LONG and  works well. And i noticed that neptune id type is actually a string.

Comment: Yes - it seems likely a little code tweak is needed where the graph-notebook parses out result data such that a diagram can be drawn and the Graph tab appears. It is intended that graph-notebook work well with a Gremlin Server. So it looks like a small change is probably needed to make sure that UUID IDs work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in graph-notebook that takes a query result and decides if it can be rendered visually ("Graph" tab), was not anticipating/handling the UUIDs that a Gremlin Server supports. It will work with string IDs or integer IDs.

The issue will be resolved by this PR https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/pull/475 once merged.